# Getting another value with regular expression with preg_split

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I am stuck for several hours with the following problem. I got my own cms where i use a shortcode `[plugin-pluginname]` to activate a plugin. Now i want to assign a group within that shortcode which is later used in the include once file as variable for a query to select that certain id.

On the moment, I got the following code:

```
$regex = '~\[plugin-([^]]+)]~';
        $content_one = htmlspecialchars_decode($page['content_one']);
        $parts = preg_split($regex, $content_one, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

        foreach($parts as $k => $v){
            if($k & 1)
                include_once('plugins/'.$v.'/'.$v.'.php');
            else
                echo htmlspecialchars_decode($v);
        }
```

This checks where there is `[plugin-testplugin]`(testplugin as an example) and includes that certain file. Now i want to write something like this `[plugin-testplugin 2]`where not only the above code still works of course, but also that the number is stored in a variable where is can use the query `SELECT * FROM 'database' WHERE 'group' = "'.$var_from_shortcode.'"`

Any help and answers to approach and solve this problem are welcome!

Comment: In this case consider to use `preg_replace_callback` instead of `preg_split`

Comment: I think preg_replace_callback might be the answer, but the tutorials of it are kinda hard. Not sure I am getting out, but I gonna try it out now!

Comment: It isn't so difficult as you think, try one or two simple tests before.

Comment: The tests are rather easy, but the implementation is not working. Maybe i can think more fresh in the morning. Thanks a lot already!

Comment: Can I accomplish this if there can be multiple `[shortcodes]` in the string?

Comment: yes off course.

Comment: I cannot get it working, can you maybe help me with an answer on how to solve it?

Comment: @Saypontigohe please try my library: https://github.com/thunderer/Shortcode . This should solve all your problems with shortcodes. If you will have any question or problem, feel free to ask me anything - just submit an issue on GitHub.

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk Thanks! I will take a look to it. The current systems already uses over 4.000 available shortcodes, but they were only for styling etc. Problems came when i made them for plugins.

Comment: @Saypontigohe with my library you will be able to bring them all under a single roof. I'm curious about your project, could you please contact me on the email from my GitHub account and tell me what are those 4000 shortcodes?

Comment: The shortcodes are things like [center]text (with all tekst after the shortcode without an enter(<br>) aligned center, to something like [track link] where the amount of clicks on that certain link is stored. I will contact you in a few days, since it is extremely busy here. Thanks for your interest :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you use [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/6RieoP/1) then save group 1 value in a variable?

```
\[plugin-[A-Za-z ]*(\d+)?\]
```

Or use this regex to find `[plugin-testplugin 2]` then use `\d*` to find the number in it?

Comment: How can I accomplish to get only the number in a single variable without the foreach loop stopping? Everything I try either stops the loop, or does not store the variable

Comment: Did you declare your variable in the same scope as where you read it? If you want to read it outside the foreach loop, I think you have to declare the variable outside it so it doesn't get destroyed.

Comment: There can be more than one `[shortcode]` in each loop, so in order to get them all I need to loop them right?

Comment: can you elaborate your answer within my problem? I am on the good way, but the foreach loop breaks when i want the value of the number